# If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous on each $U_i\subset X, i\in I$ can something be said about $f$ on $\cup_{I\in I} U_i$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I was working on some problem in algebraic topology, and I have a map that is clearly continuous, but the precise reason why is unclear, which led me to the following question :

Suppose you have a map $f:X\to Y$ between topological (or potentially metric) spaces and a family of closed sets $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ (or family of open sets). Furthermore, you know that $f$ is continuous on each $U_i$ and that $\cap_{i\in I} U_i$ is a single point in $X$. Is this enough to say that $f$ in continuous on $\cup_{i\in I} U_i$ ?
If I had to guess I'd say yes, probably, and to be fair this is probably something I should know.
Does anything change if $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ and $f$ is surjective ? If we add the hypothesis that $Y=U_i$ for some $i$ and that $f(x)=x$ for $x\in Y$ ?

To give some context I'm currently looking at the fundamental group of the infinite earring, or shrinking wedge of circle ie $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_n$ where $C_n\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a circle of radius $1/n$ centered at $(1/n,0)$ (with the subspace topology induced by the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$). I have proved that $\pi_1(X,(0,0))$ is uncountable but in my proof I sort of assumed that my space retracts nicely on some subspace and I didn't fill in the details at first, ie show that the map I defined is continuous because it seemed obvious. But for fun I tried actually showing it and I'm not sure how now, I'm fairly certain it is though. Explicitly, the retraction is $r_n: X\to C_n$ that sends each $C_i, \; i\neq n$ to the origin and fixes $C_n$. Continuity of this map seems trivial, but writing it down is bugging me. If you take an closed set in $C_n$ that doesn't include the origin then it's preimage by $r_n$ is itself which is closed. And if you take a closed set that includes the origin than it's preimage is all of the $C_i$ for $i\neq n$. Now all the $C_i$ are closed but it's not super obvious that their union is ? Similarly when I try proving continuity looking at the the preimage of open sets I run into a somewhat similar issue. But still I'm fairly confident $r_n$ is continuous, so this got me wondering if something could be said in general hence the question above. I tried scribbling down something on paper but I don't really know what to do.

Comment: When you say "continuous on $U_i$" do you mean that the restriction $f\Bigr|_{U_i}: U_i \to Y$ is continuous in the subspace topology on the domain?

Comment: @Randall To be entirely honest I hadn't quite considered which topology I was considering on $U_i$ ; but upon reflexion, yes I think this what I want to mean.

Comment: See the pasting lemma:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma (which is a necessary ingredient in defining the homotopy groups)

Comment: @Randall Thank you, looking it up right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a closed family $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ : NO. Let $X=Y=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. Let $I=\Bbb R$ and let $U_i=\{i,0\}.$ Then $U_i$ is a discrete space, and any function on a discrete space is continuous, so $any$ $f:X\to Y$ meets the conditions.

For an open family $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ : YES. There are many useful equivalent definitions of continuity. A function $f:A\to Y$ is locally continuous iff every $a\in A$ has a nbhd $U_a$ such that $f|_{U_a}$ is continuous. It is a simple exercise to show that a function is continuous iff it is locally continuous. Each $U_i$ is open in $X$ so each $U_i$ is open in $A=\cup_{i\in I}U_i,$ so $f:A\to Y$ is  locally continuous, hence continuous. The condition $\cap_{i\in I}U_i\ne \emptyset$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question so it can be closed.
As suggested by Randall in the comments, the pasting lemma does solve the problem.
If $A=X\cup Y$ is a topological space and $X,Y$ are open sets and $f:A\to B$ ($B$ is also a topological space) is continuous when restricted to both $X$ and $Y$ then $f$ is continuous. This is also true for finite collections of closed sets, more generally locally finite collections of closed sets, and arbitrary collections of open sets.